# Adding notes to full calendar day and week view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add additional notes to an event for the day and week view of the full calendar. Ideally, you can click a title on the day while on the month view and it would switch to the day view with the extra notes in the field block. I have addend a picture to help explain it, thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultDate: '2020-06-11',
        selectable: true,
        selectHelper: true,
        select: function(start, end) {
            var title = prompt('Event Title:');
            var eventData;
            if (title) {
                eventData = {
                    title: title,
                    start: start,
                    end: end
                };
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
            }
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
        },
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: [
            {
                title: "A team",
                start: '08:00', // a start time (10am in this example)
                end: '10:00', // an end time (2pm in this example)
                dow: [ 0, 6 ], // Repeat monday and thursday    
                description: "Attending: <br> BA,Face,Hannibal,Murdock"     
            }
        ]
    });

});
```

[image]

Comment: It isn't clear what your question is - does the code you've shared not work? Or have you not tried anything yet?  SO isn't a free code-writing service, and you'll get a better response if you show that you've made some effort, eg show us what you've tried, why you tried that, describe what happens, etc.  Please visit the help centre and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), and how to create a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of unsuccessful attempts, I abandoned the javascript and used css. First, use a "\n" in your title and put a note after that. Like this;

```
title: 'A team \n Attending: \n BA, Face, Hannibal, Murdock',
```

Then add css to hide the second (and so on) line.

```
<style type="text/css">
.fc-day-grid-event > .fc-content {
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
cursor: pointer; 
max-height:15px;
}
</style>
```

[image]

It would be cool if I could figure out how to put an id on '' so I could add some html to it, but this works for now.